# MySQL-select and sort rows based on the keys and values of json array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table with 2 columns in my database: `id` and `data`. some information is saved in json format in data column. for example:

```
id     data
---------------------------
1      [{"id":10,"score":0.68},{"id":20,"score":0.59}]
2      [{"id":15,"score":0.95},{"id":13,"score":0.89}]
...
```

now I need to run a query which selects the rows whose ids exist in the json array of the first row (i.e. the rows with id=10 or id=20), and then sort those rows by the score value mentioned in the json array. how to run such queries?

```
expected output:

id
-----
20
10
```

Comment: What is your exact desired output here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated the post and mentioned.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MariaDB 10.5.8

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB have no function which parses JSON value to the rowset (like JSON_TABLE in MySQL), so use recusive CTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS (
SELECT 0 num, JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[', 0, '].id')) id
FROM test
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 + num, JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[', 1 + num, '].id'))
FROM test
CROSS JOIN cte
WHERE test.id = 1
  AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[', 1 + num, '].id')) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id FROM cte
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=8a1a8178eab2e6d3c4da51ae59a5d59d

If each `data` value contains strictly 2 elements in JSON array then you may hardcode the indexes:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[0].id')) id
FROM test
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[1].id')) 
FROM test
WHERE id = 1
```